# Unable to get images in list in Django views.py context, Throws List AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, webserver

I am using below code to get a list of all image and then display it:

```
def index(request):
    data = cos.list_objects(Bucket='pixmedia')
    di = data['Contents']
    endpoint="https://s3.us.cloud-object-storage.XXXXX.cloud/XXX/"
    #print(di)
    image_list=[]
    for key in di:
        print("Key is--->",key['Key'])
        res=key['Key']
        res=endpoint + res
        print("Res is ---->",res)

        #context = {
        #    'image': res,
        #}
        image_list=image_list.append(res)
        print("Image List is",image_list)



    context = {
            {'image_list': image_list,}
    }

    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

But, i am getting below error on launching 127.0.0.1:8000:

image_list=image_list.append(res)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Change `image_list=image_list.append(res)` to `image_list.append(res)`. You are reassigning image_list but there is no return value for the append method, hence the NoneType error. Lists are mutable so it modifies the list in place.

Comment: I have tried this - image_list.append(res). Now, i am getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' . This is coming from context i guess.

Comment: Yes, your context should only have 1 set of curly braces

Comment: Now, I am getting all the image URL in the image_list but nothing is displayed on the browser.